# General Wikipedia HTML structure

Tags: python, html, wikipedia

Is there a general format for Wikipedia's HTML tags? i.e. apart from the basics (head, tite, body, etc.) are there particular tags to separate each block of info? Say for example, the introduction may have tag `<p>`, while Sections 1,2,3 may have tags `<s1>, <s2>, <s3>`?

I need to be able to get the content differentiated by section. Also, I'm not using the wikipedia api to get this info, only Python.

Comment: Why don't you use the API?

Answer (score 3):

As an on and off editor at Wikipedia, editors don't tend to use the `<p>` tags, let alone many HTML tags. Infact, they follow [their own set of rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aManual_of_Style).

MediaWiki is pretty much a replacement for HTML, but some HTML tags do work (i.e, `<span>`s for colouring text, etc). Also, sections are not done in HTML. Compare:

HTML: `<h2>A header</h2>`

MediaWiki: `==A header==`

If you want to get the content from each header, then definitely use their API. Here's a link about editing pages through the API: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Edit.